# Github Pages on main domain. WordPress Blog on a subdomain

Tags: dns, hosting

So let's say I have a domain `example.com`. I want to have a static website hosted on Github Pages on the root of the domain.

It will also have other subdomains like `example.com/about` and `example.com/projects`. I want to have a subdomain at `example.com/blog` hosted with a shared hosting running a WordPress blog.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`example.com/blog` is not a subdomain. A subdomain would be something like `blog.example.com`. You could point a subdomain to your WordPress site by creating a record for the subdomain with your DNS provider that points to your WordPress site.

`example.com/blog` has to be routed by the static page that is hosted at GitHub pages. A simple way to do this might be to serve a static page with a iFrame of your WordPress site. You can also use the [jekyll-redirect-from gem](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/), if you are using jekyll.